# Fixed background image being moved during scroll

Tags: css, background-image

Okay, I tried to remove all the extraneous stuff to a) see if I could find what the issue was, and b) make it easier to post.  I have not found the issue, so.. onto plan b!

I have a #page-wrapper that I *think* should be static, allowing the content to scroll over it, but I'm obviously missing something, since scrolling down reveals a white background.  Any thoughts would be *greatly* appreciated!

```
    #page-wrapper {
      background: url(https://templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_543_breezed/assets/images/slide-02.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bjwxfyop/

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow: scroll;` to your `#page-wrapper`?

Comment: @Martin: That introduces scrollbars, it works, so I'll take it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@zimdanen. I think the issue here is the height being provided as the viewport height. As the content is scrollable either give it 100% or else you can completely remove the height property. Overflow scroll works but I doubt it reflects the actual height of the wrapper if u check the dev tools

```
#page-wrapper {
  display: table;
  background: url(https://templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_543_breezed/assets/images/slide-02.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: That becomes an issue if the content is less than one viewport.

Comment: @zimdanen oh. got it! that can be an issue. I think this will work perfectly if you add display: table props to the page wrapper. I have updated my answer

Comment: That does it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So, over here you are not required to mention height and width.

`div`'s will naturally resize in accordance with their content.

If you set no height on your div, it will expand to contain its content.

```
#page-wrapper {
  background: url(https://templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_543_breezed/assets/images/slide-02.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: That becomes an issue if the content is less than one viewport.